# How to integrate boost thread(source files) into my own project

Tags: c++, boost, dll, cmake, boost-thread

What I want is to put the source files about the boost thread(all necessary header and source files) into my own project so that other people don't need to configure the support of boost anymore. The build system is made by CMake.

Recently I am trying to update the boost thread to the actual version 1.53, but the new version of boost thread cannot get built in windows.(it works under linux)

What I do to integrate the boost thread is very simple, I just put all source files required by boost::thread in one folder (including the source files of boost::system) and make a DLL for all these source files. (with build option BOOST_THREAD_BUILD_DLL)

But when the built dll library above is linked to my own code, I got some unresolved reference errors to the boost::system like:

```
"unresolved reference to error_category xxxx"
```

But the built library contains the source files from the boost::system, I have no idea why such error comes. Could you guys give me some hints? thanks a lot, I have already spent quite time about this disgusting probem :(

Comment: Why don't you simply list boost thread as a dependency, and let the user install it ? (or ship a compiled version with your code)

Comment: boost has an own tool for that which actually works. i used it before.

Comment: Thanks all. It is not decided by meself, from my view I would ofc like to list the boost thread as a external dependency :( @JohannesSchaub-litb Could you tell the tool for that ?

Comment: Do you want to redistribute the source code without dependency on Boost, or an executable that include the boost threads? In the latest case, just use the static linking to the Boost libraries

Comment: @PaoloBrandoli I want to redistribute the source code without dependency on Boost, the boost::thread will be built inside of the project.

Answer (score 2):

As Johannes pointed out in his comment, the [BCP](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html) tool is designed to do exactly this:

> The bcp utility is a tool for extracting subsets of Boost, it's useful for Boost authors who want to distribute their library separately from Boost, and for Boost users who want to distribute a subset of Boost with their application.

Comment: Hi, @JonathanWakely BCP only extracts the necessary files for a certain part separately from Boost, but the strange and complicate macros defined in the head files remains in the separate part of code. I have the same error as before when I use the code extracted by BCP.